# Trying to access our app service api with a user assigned identity in azure functions

Tags: c#, api, authentication, azure-functions

I am sorry if this has been asked and answered before, I've searched like a madman, and I can't find the answer to my problem. To start off with I am a junior developer, still in school actually so please don't cut my head off (I've heard horror stories).

We are currently building a blazor wasm application and there are a few functions I need to trigger on a weekly basis, so azure functions with a timer trigger seemed appropriate, with a user-assigned identity to authenticate towards our API.

[image: Right now, the function looks like this]

Right now, the function looks like this

The resource Uri is our app service URI identifier: "api://xxxx-xxxx..." etc.

I get a token from this setup, but I can't reach the API. The detailed log says that neither scope nor claim was found in the bearer. And it might be worth mentioning that even if I turn off authorization on our controller, I still can't reach it. I get the same error.

If I get a token from "https://management.azure.com/" then it works without authorization on the controller. So, I am clearly missing something. But from all examples, I can find this should be the appropriate way to do this.

[image: On our client-side our authentication looks like this]

On our client-side our authentication looks like this

[image: And our httpmessagehandler looks like this]

And our httpmessagehandler looks like this

I would appreciate any help at all, any links that can help me solve this problem.

/Sonny

Comment: I have an older article on this: https://joonasw.net/view/calling-your-apis-with-aad-msi-using-app-permissions. Basically you need to know that there is no scope claim here, there can only be a roles claim if you define an app permission (appRole). You either need to define an app permission and check for that, or check the oid/appid claim to verify it is that specific caller.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I love YOU! <3

Answer (score 0):

Thank You [juunas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1658906/juunas) for your valuable suggestion. Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

> If you define an app permission which means appRole, there can only be a roles claim.
> Either you need to define an app permission and check for that or check the oid/appid claim to verify it is that specific caller.